# How to unlock multithreading of third-party DLLs in Delphi?

Tags: c, multithreading, delphi, vcl, pthreads-win32

I have a DLL written in C that uses pthreads-w32 threads. When I connected it in a .NET Framework program, the threads worked correctly. But now I'm using VCL, and when I try to start a thread from a DLL function, the program hangs intentionally.

I tried to set the `IsMultiThread := True` variable in the program itself, but this should be done from inside the DLL, and it has nothing to do with the VCL. Is there any way out of this situation?

Comment: `IsMultiThread` doesn't affect C. If the DLL works fine in .NET, there should be no reason that it wouldn't also work fine in Delphi.  Something else has to be going on. Can you provide a [mcve] showing how the DLL is creating/managing the thread, and how the app is using the DLL?